# How can I get Facebook's access token do display my page's feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display facebook page feed using a JavaScript plugin (https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed in this case).

The plugin requires access_token to get the data. So far, as I understand, the only way to programatically generate a token is to

a) Create a Facebook app

b) Fill all the data, terms & conditions, add an icon

c) Request public page access and submit a review request with all the explanations on how the app will be used, seen by users etc.

d) Use the app ID and app secret to generate access_token of the app which will have the access to the Page feed

This seems to be a lot of work to just display a feed of my own page.

This Facebook "App" will not be used by any external users, it will just be used to get the feed from the API.

Is there any faster and easier way to display my page's feed, other than creating a Facebook App ?

I can generate a user token which will be a faster way to get the data but it expires quickly.

Facebook page profiles are public, so why would I need to request some permissions to access my page?

Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other way, and the only way that works without review, is to use a Page Token of that Page. You can use an Extended Page Token, it is valid for 60 days: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

When it is expired, you need to refresh it manually, of course.